# How to find high fanout nets?

Tags: verilog, synthesis, asic, timing-analysis, rtl

In the timing report of a synthesis with Synopsys VCS, a warning states:

> Warning: Design contains 8 high-fanout nets. A fanout number of 1000 will be used for delay calculations involving these nets. (TIM-134)

How can I find the offending nets? Is there any report that I can use to find these high-fanout nets?

Crossposted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285594/how-to-find-high-fanout-nets-in-vcs?noredirect=1#comment50563432_31285594

Comment: Don't you mean Design Compiler?

Comment: @Vitor: Perhaps! I think we invoke vcs to compile, not sure what it stands for. :/

Comment: VCS is for simulation. Design Compiler is used for synthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Design Compiler you can use the command `all_high_fanout -nets` to obtain a collection of nets that has a fanout value bigger than `high_fanout_net_threshold` variable, which you can review using the command `report_app_var high_fanout_net_threshold`. A specific threshold `N` can also defined using the command:

```
all_high_fanout -net -threshold N
```

The reported high fanout nets are typically clock networks. If that is the case, you will see that the timing reports will have a huge increment in those nets, making timing closure much harder. Since the high-fanout issue is resolved during Clock Tree Synthesis of the Place & Route phase those timing reports are too pessimistic. To overcome this you can define the clock networks as ideal by using the command `set_ideal_network` on the affected ports/pins.

Answer (score 0):

If a clock out from a clock generator is driving clock inputs of 10 other clock receiver ICs (assume), then the fan out of the clock generator IC is 10. In your case it might be the net which is connected to **many** other nodes. And hence, the software is assuming 1000 fan outs. (Equivalent load of 1000 clock receivers).

This might be to predict the worst case delay (Maximum operable speed at high load). Sharing a rough drawing of the offending net connections,if available, will help.

Comment: How to know which the offending nets are? Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: only a person with the experience in that tool can answer that, sorry!